# Android download manager get stuck when I pause and then resume

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I'm writing a file downloader for my app.  here is how I pause and resume the android download manager:

```
public static boolean resumeDownload(Context context, Long downloadManagerId) {
    int updatedRows = 0;

    ContentValues resumeDownload = new ContentValues();
    resumeDownload.put("control", 0); // Resume Control Value

    try {
        updatedRows = context
                .getContentResolver()
                .update(Uri.parse("content://downloads/my_downloads"),
                        resumeDownload,
                        "_id=?",
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(downloadManagerId)});
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return 0 < updatedRows;
}

public static boolean pauseDownload(Context context, Long downloadManagerId) {
    int updatedRows = 0;

    ContentValues pauseDownload = new ContentValues();
    pauseDownload.put("control", 1); // Pause Control Value

    try {
        updatedRows = context
                .getContentResolver()
                .update(Uri.parse("content://downloads/my_downloads"),
                        pauseDownload,
                        "_id=?",
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(downloadManagerId)});
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return 0 < updatedRows;
}
```

the problem is that when I pause and resume a downloading file it get stuck for some seconds! Is there any other way to pause and resume in android?

Comment: any solution? also facing same issue.

Comment: I didn't found any solution yet! @AZyre